# Own app is loading infinitely with Quickblox

Tags: java, android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, quickblox

I made an android app just like this tutorial : 
[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5AhghMG9Y1I I can register and sign in without any problems but after logging in it stays forever in the screen "Loading" and it doesnt open the next activity where I can start chatting with other users. The android monitor says:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                              Process: com.example.georg.chatapp, PID: 31740
>                                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String com.quickblox.users.model.QBUser.getLogin()' on a
>   null object reference
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.georg.chatapp.ListUsersActivity$4.onSuccess(ListUsersActivity.java:160)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.example.georg.chatapp.ListUsersActivity$4.onSuccess(ListUsersActivity.java:149)

Here is the code where its linked to:

```
private void retrieveAllUsers() {

        QBUsers.getUsers(null).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> qbUsers, Bundle bundle) {

                //add cache
                QBUsersHolder.getInstance().putUsers(qbUsers);


                ArrayList<QBUser> qbUserWithoutCurrent = new ArrayList<QBUser>();
                for (QBUser user : qbUsers)
                {
                    if (!user.getLogin().equals(QBChatService.getInstance().getUser().getLogin()))
                        qbUserWithoutCurrent.add(user);
                }

                ListUsersAdapter adapter = new ListUsersAdapter(getBaseContext(),qbUserWithoutCurrent);
                lstUsers.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());

            }
        });
    }
```

User Login:

```
private void createSessionForChat() {
        final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatDialogsActivity.this);
        mDialog.setMessage("Verbindung wird hergestellt");
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialog.show();

        String user,password;
        user = getIntent().getStringExtra("user");
        password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");

        final QBUser qbUser = new QBUser(user,password);
        QBAuth.createSession(qbUser).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bundle) {
                qbUser.setId(qbSession.getUserId());
                try {
                    qbUser.setPassword(BaseService.getBaseService().getToken());
                } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                QBChatService.getInstance().login(qbUser, new QBEntityCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                        Log.e("ERROR",""+e.getMessage());

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

            }
        });
    }
```

I hope you have an idea how to solve it. I use QuickBlox as server.
When I press the "back" button while its loading the next activity with the floating button appears for some secconds and then it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It happen because no user is logged in to the chat (maybe logged to the REST but not to chat). In your case you need login to the chat before loading users, for it use `QBChatService.getInstance().login(qbUser);`
qbUser - QBUser with id, login and password.

Comment: thanks for your help. The user login is in another class and should work. I have added it to the post.

Comment: you can see log and found next text in logs "D/SMACK: XMPPConnection authenticated (0)" or before call your code check login state as QBChatService.getInstance().isLoggedIn();